# What is the nuance of わかりゃあせん vs regular わかりません?

Tags: colloquial-language, particle-は, dialects, negation, contractions

I heard the following phrase spoken in Osaka:

> そう泣いてばかりでは**わかりゃあせん**

Is it regional? Does it have any nuance to it?

Is it a more regular pattern or just an intonation of this particular phrase?

(Googling shows some わかりゃせん, but it also seems a spoken dialect; anyway I could not find any dictionary reference)

Comment: Just did some research - looks like this is [Mikawa dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikawa_dialect) spoken in Aichi Pref.

Comment: 「わかりやしない」「わかるわけがない」みたいな感じですかね・・・

Comment: この表現は、使用されている地域が広大すぎて、単純に「方言」と読んでよいものかどうか迷うところです。「非常にニュートラルな方言」、もしくは、「方言らしくない方言」とでも言いましょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*tl;dr* It is regional speaking, and former has emphasis on it where latter doesn't.

Here's what I found. This wording can be found in [三河弁](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikawa_dialect). Although this is spoken in Aichi, I (from Hyogo) do speak this sometimes.

In this dialect, **〜や(あ)せん** in the regular form is **〜や しない**.
So **わかりゃあせん** in regular form is **わかりやしない**.

Now, **わかりません** vs **わかりやしない(わかりやしません)** is slightly different.

We'll break わかりやしない into words...

> わかり/や/し/ない

where **や** is very interesting. *や* is actually `Engagement particle` **は** turned into casual speaking.

(Cf. http://lang-8.com/81029/journals/227496511358989883065326511567758757626)

So that being said, this phrase is originally **わかりはしない**, whose *basic meaning* is "わからない". This **は emphasizes preceding word**. So it can be interpreted as "**I(we)'ll *never* know.**"

What about わかりません? It's simply "*I don't know*," no emphasis put. That's the difference between them.

Comment: As @l'électeur pointed out, this phrase is so widely used that it's a little bit hard to call it dialectal. As I mentioned in the answer, although this phrase can be found in Mikawa dialect which is spoken in Aichi, I from Kansai Area do use this phrase. Still, the meaning is the same.